# Not able to connect metamask account with remix

Tags: remix, metamask, rinkeby

Error: -
Cannot get account list: Error: The method personal_listAccounts does not exist/is not available.

Pop containing above message appears again and again.

Privacy Mode in metamask is disabled.

[image: Screenshot of remix editor]

Comment: Perhaps is something related to this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69135/issue-with-new-version-of-metamask-remix-cannot-detect-the-metamask-address ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Privacy Mode in Metamask is disabled under Settings > Security & Privacy

Comment: Thanks @ziad for answer.. along with the disabling privacy mode in metamask we also have to ensure that personal mode in remix is also disabled.